# Confusion between Kirchhoff's current law and voltage law

Tags: current, kirchhoffs-laws

My wire is running 5 volts, 2 amps. I am splitting that wire into two. I want to make sure 1 amp goes to each half. According to Kirchhoff's law, that is possible, because it states that the sum of currents through all wires on the receiving side of the junction (node) is equal to the sum of currents through all wires on the supplying side.

However, I don't understand it properly. What is the "loop" in Kirchhoff's voltage law? Is there a difference between KVL and KCL?

Comment: The trick is to ensure that the load on each wire is exactly 5 ohms so it takes exactly 1A at 5V. If you can't guarantee that each load is 5 ohms, you'll have to describe what you're really trying to do.

Comment: thanks so i add a 5 ohm resistor on the two halves o the wire

Comment: By the way, it's written *Kirchhoff's law*. You will find better information about it using the correct spelling.

Comment: @AliRagb "add a 5 ohm resistor..." - no. Why are you splitting the wire into two?

Comment: @AndrewMorton  because i have two amps 5 volts, and i want to power two  5 volt 1 amp devices

Comment: @AliRagb If each device draws 1 amp then the current will be split equally between the two wires automatically (as long as the wires have the same small resistance). The amount of current flowing through a device is determined by the voltage across that device. It may be that they are *rated* at 1 A but actually draw a little less than that. Without knowing what the devices are, I can't comment further on that.

Comment: @AndrewMorton  one of my devices draws one amp. the other one can take anything but i want it to take one amp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two basic ways you can do this.

[image]

By Ohm's law if you have a current of 2A from a voltage of 5V then the load must equal 2.5 Ohms.

In circuit A if we add an identical piece of wire (same material, cross-sectional area and length) between X and Y the current will split equally (2A --> 1A + 1A) between the two wires at point X. At point Y the two currents will recombine back to the 2A (1A + 1A --> 2A).

Alternatively (circuit B) you could double the load resistance to form two parallel loads of 5 Ohms. Two 5 Ohms in parallel giving the original load of 2.5 Ohms. Feed each 5 Ohm with a separate wire from point X. In which case the 2A current will split at point X (2A --> 1A + 1A) and 1A will pass through each 5 Ohm load with the currents recombining at the common load connection before returning to the negative terminal of the battery.

Comment: @Jlm Dearden  but is it going to split exactly , or is it not. Wouldnt adding two 5ohm resistors going to help let exactly 5 volts one amp?

Comment: The two (identical) 5 Ohms are in parallel making it the equivalent of 2.5 Ohms. This makes for **two current loops of 1A each** giving the original 2A total current. It will split exactly provided that the two resistors (circuit B)  or wires (circuit A) **are identical**.